# Jena oddly thinks individual rdf:type is "#NamedIndividual" on random individuals

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, ontology

I noticed Jena was giving me a conversion error whenever I called ".getOntClass()" on some individuals. I did some further testing, and when I call ".getRDFType()" on some individuals, it incorrectly returns "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual" instead of the correct rdf:type that is stated in the ontology. Here are the individuals in question in the ontology:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000250">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000076"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000370"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000542"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000550"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000602"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000603"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000604"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000179 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000154"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Haas-DM1VerticalMill</rdfs:label>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000256">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000076"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000544"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000549"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000551"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000605"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000606"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000607"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000179 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000154"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Haas-DM2VerticalMill</rdfs:label>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000155">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000076"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000128"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000581"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000601"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000608"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000609"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000130 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL#MSDL_0000610"/>
    <msdl:MSDL_0000179 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000154"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Haas-VF1VerticalMill</rdfs:label>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

The first individual (Haas-DM1VerticalMill) correctly returns "http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000076" when I call ".getRDFType()" on it. But the other two individuals (Haas-DM2VerticalMill and Haas-VF1VerticalMill) incorrectly return "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual" instead of "http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000076".

Strangely, when I get rid of the line "msdl:MSDL_0000179 rdf:resource="http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000154"" in the two problem individuals, ".getRDFType()" returns "http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000076" as it should. I don't know why this is, especially considering the Haas-DM1 individual has that line as well and works fine with it included.

Setting strict mode to false changes nothing. Any help?

Comment: What do you think is wrong? The type `owl:NamedIndividual` is correct for each individual. It is directly stated in the opening tag for each individual, this is another way in RDF/XML syntax to define the type of a resource.

Comment: It would also be good to see the Java code...

Comment: Moreover, you should read [the Javadoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#getRDFType--) It states that it returns one type randomly - if there is more than one type - which is the case here - you have to call `listRDFTypes` which returns an iterator.

Comment: Also, you could try [`.getRDFType(true)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#getRDFType-boolean-).

Comment: @StanislavKralin That won't help as both are direct types according to the `RDF/XML` document, thus, one of the two classes.

Comment: @AKSW THANK YOU! I didn't realize owl:NamedIndividual was considered an rdf type in the same sense that the stated rdf:type is an rdf type. I ran an iterator with individual.listRDFTypes and it turns out each individual has two types -- owl:NamedIndividual and rdf:type. And so I guess individual.getRDFType returns one of the types at random if there are multiple. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, yes - the serialization format RDF/XML is not really intended for human reading. I'd always suggest Turtle for RDF data and Manchester OWL syntax for OWL data. Cheers

Comment: @AKSW, is _Manchester OWL syntax_ a serialization format that Jena can output? I don't see anything similar in `RDFFormat`.

Comment: No, there isn't. I just wanted to say that in general this format is more concise and directly reflects the OWL axioms. RDF/XML is indeed the format supported by most of the tools working with OWL. You could use the OWL API if you're working with OWL.

Comment: Now that I think of it, isn't the individual.getOntClass() method basically useless if it always has the possibility of returning "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"?